# Deletion of AWS resources status delayed

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, newrelic

Using AWS Cloudwatch metrics stream integration with New Relic, some resources like EC2, ELB/ALB, and RDS deletion status is delayed for about 30 minutes to one hour. What is the cause of this delay? Is there a documentation for this?

Sample query:

FROM Metric SELECT uniqueCount(aws.ec2.InstanceId) as 'Failed Instances' WHERE collector.name = 'cloudwatch-metric-streams' AND newrelic.cloudIntegrations.providerAccountId = '*****' AND aws.ec2.state != 'running' EXTRAPOLATE

Comment: "deletion status is delayed for about 30 minutes to one hour": what exactly does it mean?  which metric are your looking at?

Comment: Update the question with sample query.

Comment: What does this query return and what did you expect it to return?

Comment: The status of the ec2 instance when terminated is delayed for about 30 minutes or more.

Answer (score 1):

The metric streams only include the bare metrics. Then we have another process that retrieves metadata from AWS every so often, and that metadata is stamped onto the metrics.

That’s why, even if the stream changes and we reflect the change in pseudo-real time, the accompanying metadata will only be updated in the next harvesting cycle, which runs every 15 minutes by default.

Then the metadata needs to be ingested an updated in different places, which can take up to 10+ additional minutes.